# How to install SSL certificate for domain and subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I want to install certificate on Ec2 for domains and subdomains.

I'm running a website "www.example.in" on single EC2 instance which is in public subnet with public IP and also pointing some subdomains like "api.example.in", "dashboard.example.in" and "jenkins.example.in" to the same EC2 instance.

I thought to use ACM certificate to secure my website but ACM certificate can't be use directly on EC2 instance.

If i use third party tools like "let's encrypt". If I install certificate directly on EC2, will it block my subdomains or will impact on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ACM (Amazon certs)
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-acm-certificates-ec2/

Without ACM (bring your own cert)
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html

No, it will not block your website. "Let's encrypt" works just fine. I have worked with it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your subdomains, you can create a wildcard certificate that can provide SSL for example.in and all subdomains (e.g. api.example.in, dashboard.example.in).

Let's Encrypt supports [wildcard certs](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578).